# Qt5.7 QML FileDialog Open/Save opens first item instead of selected item

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

Currently I am experiencing issues with the Qt QML FileDialog. This problem exists on multiple systems & in the production code and a test application (see code block below).

The dialog opens propperly, but when a file is selected (that is not the first file on the list, so imagine:

- FolderFoo
- FolderFaa
- FileToOpen
- FileFoo

Then when clicking the open(or save) button the folder "FolderFoo" is opened in the dialog instead of closing the FileDialog and logging the filepath of "FileToOpen".

It is very simple to reproduce with a QML application:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 1280
    height: 640
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Button {
        id: openButton
        width: 640
        height: 640
        text: qsTr("Open")
        onClicked: {
            fileDialog.title = "Open file"
            fileDialog.nameFilters = [ "All files (*)" ]
            fileDialog.selectExisting = true
            fileDialog.open()
        }
    }
    Button {
        id: saveButton
        width: 640
        height: 640
        anchors.left: openButton.right
        text: qsTr("Save")
        onClicked: {
            fileDialog.title = "Save to file"
            fileDialog.nameFilters = [ "All files (*)" ]
            fileDialog.selectExisting = false
            fileDialog.open()
        }
    }

    FileDialog {
        id: fileDialog
        width: 1000
        height: 600
        folder: shortcuts.home
        selectMultiple: false
        selectFolder: false
        onAccepted: {
            if(fileDialog.selectExisting == true) {
                console.log(fileDialog.fileUrl)
            }
            else {
                console.log(fileDialog.fileUrl)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The same behaviour is shown when using nameFilters, but sometimes it just works. No real reason is shown why.

When the file is at a dead end of folders (so no child folders) then the open/save button works as expected.

Would anyone know of a solution to this issue?

Comment: It seems a bug. Same behavior with [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickdialogs-systemdialogs-filedialogs-qml.html) example. Anyway, if I use double click to open the file instead of the Open button, it works.

Comment: Yup, double clicking works. For good measure I reported the bug to Qt.

For future reference (and anyone interrested): https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-56663